# React-Native unable to store state getting null

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile-application

I'm new to React-native so if there is a misunderstanding please be super clear and treat me as if I have never seen React-native before.

I have the app so that when you press on a button it will send you into an Auth0 flow where you can log in to the app. This seems working. If I log out the access token directly in the callback I am successful in getting it at the `credentials.accessToken` variable/location. However, when I am trying to set the state of the `accessToken` variable I get back `null` when I try to log it out to the screen via an alert or even via `console.log`. What am I doing wrong to cause this? I tried searching SO and google but both seem to show this as the right way of doing it.

Code:

```
const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(null)

    const onLogin = () => {
        auth0.webAuth
            .authorize({
                scope: 'openid profile email'
            })
            .then(credentials => {
                setAccessToken(credentials.accessToken)
                Alert.alert('Access token: ', accessToken)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error)) // Eventually send this to backend for crash reporting
    }
```

Comment: Please make 100% sure that console.log(credentials.accessToken) does not return null in the callback?

Comment: @ShameelUddin Yes I already did that long before posting also if I put it into the alert instead of console log it shows the access token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a case of a state not updating immediately.  Try to use a useRef() instead of a useState(https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useref.asp).  If the problem is solved the issue was with the fact that states are updated asynchronously and hence it was not set to its most recent value (the value you expected) when you console logged it.

Comment: Thanks that seems to have worked to allow me to assign it to a variable.